# Using SMTP to send emails in PHP getting blank pge

Tags: php, smtp

I am trying to send emails using SMTP Server in Core HP. I am getting a blank page not displaying any errors. Can any one help me out? what i am doing wrong? Unable to check the issue as well!

```
<?php ob_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit_contact'])) {       
    require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';  
$to = "abc@gmail.com";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$txt = $_POST['comment'];
        $mail = new PHPMailer(); 
 $mail->IsSMTP(); 
 $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; 
 $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
 $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
 $mail->Port = 465; 
 $mail->IsHTML(true);
 $mail->Username = "abc@gmail.com";
 $mail->Password = "password1@3";
 $mail->SetFrom('$email');
 $mail->Subject = $subject;
 $mail->Body = $txt;
 $mail->AddAddress($to);
 if(!$mail->Send()) {
 echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 } else {
echo "Message has been sent";
}

}
?>
```

Comment: check out error and mail logs

Comment: Try using die in each step to find the issue, The code is executable

Comment: @Ghost displaying this error PHP Warning:  require(PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  but i have uploaded PHPMailer directory in that

Comment: Change your last line before `?>` to `} else { echo 'submit_contact is not set' ; }`. It looks like you are not getting the $_POST Value you expect

Comment: @MrGlass getting this error after adding this app.domain.website is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: @user9131066, you posted your comment about the "failed to open" error while I was typing my comment. You should ignore my previous comment and find the issue causing the "failed to open" error.

Comment: Changed the require function like this require ('./PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
 once click on submit redirecting to same page in error logs as well their are no errors.But unable to receive email

Comment: check the path of the file that is included. PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php

Comment: @sree this was the path /public_html/aaa/PHPMailer

Comment: @user9131066 is your source code located at public_html folder? In that case you have to include like below
require 'aaa/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is your source code located at public_html folder? 
In that case you have to include like below

```
require 'aaa/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
```

Comment: In Body message i need to include name,email as well